# How to read CSV file stored in variable

Tags: bash, shell, csv, unix

I want to read a CSV file using Shell,
But for some reason it doesn't work.

I use this to locate the latest added csv file in my csv folder

```
lastCSV=$(ls -t csv-output/ | head -1)
```

and this to count the lines.

```
wc -l $lastCSV
```

Output

```
wc: drupal_site_livinglab.csv: No such file or directory
```

If I echo the file it says: drupal_site_livinglab.csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you're one directory up from the path you are trying to read. The quick fix would be `wc -l "csv-output/$lastCSV"`.

Bear in mind that parsing `ls -t` though convenient, isn't completely robust, so you should consider something like this to protect you from awkward file names:

```
last_csv=$(find csv-output/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -printf '%T@\t%p\0' |
  sort -znr | head -zn1 | cut -zf2-)
wc -l "$last_csv"
```

- GNU `find` lists all files along with their last modification time, separating the output using null bytes to avoid problems with awkward filenames.

  - if you remove `-maxdepth 1`, this will become a recursive search
- GNU `sort` arranges the files from newest to oldest, with `-z` to accept null byte-delimited input.
- GNU `head -z` returns the first record from the sorted list.
- GNU `cut -z` at the end discards the timestamp, leaving you with only the filename.

You can also replace `find` with `stat` (again, this assumes that you have GNU coreutils):

```
last_csv=$(stat csv-output/* --printf '%Y\t%n\0' | sort -znr | head -zn1 | cut -zf2-)
```

Comment: Is there a way to store the amount of lines into another variable?

Comment: If you want to count the number of files, just use `files=( csv-output/* ); echo "${#files[@]}"`.